# Cannot open a component of a shared module via PopoverController

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a ChatPage component in my ionic 5.0.0 project. I just want to open that ChatPage through PopOverController. I know that I have to import the ChatPage module in app.module.ts in-order to open it via PopOverController. I have done this for other component successfully. But here the problem is ChatPage component is a part of a Shared Module. So i'm importing the shared module to every other modules wherever the chat page is required. (rather than importing the shared module in app.module.ts, i'm importing it to each individual modules).

So whenever i'm trying to open ChatPage componet as a popover browser console gives me following error.

```html
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for ChatPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for ChatPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:9877)
    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:9915)
    at attachView (fesm5.js:2976)
    at fesm5.js:2917
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17299)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at NgZone.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run (core.js:17213)
    at fesm5.js:2912
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at zone.js:741
    at rejected (tslib.js:69)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17299)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)
    at zone.js:889
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
```

Here is the **shared.module.ts**

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { ChatPage } from '../chat/chat.page';

const routes: Routes = [
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [ChatPage],
  exports: [ChatPage]
})
export class SharedPageModule {}
```

I'm importing this Shared module as follows in other modules wherever i need the Chat functionality.

**home.page.ts**

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { SharedPageModule } from '../shared/shared.module'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ]),
    SharedPageModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Here is my **app.module.ts**

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { PopoverPageModule } from './popover/popover.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { GlobalFunctions } from '../providers/global-functions';
import { AuthGuard } from '../providers/security/auth-guard';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import { HttpProvider } from '../providers/http/http';
import { HttpAngularProvider } from '../providers/http/http-angular';
import { HttpNativeProvider } from '../providers/http/http-native';
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';
import { NgxUiLoaderModule } from  'ngx-ui-loader';
import { IonicGestureConfig } from '../providers/IonicGestureConfig';
import { HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    HttpClientModule, 
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule, 
    PopoverPageModule,
    //ChatPageModule --> I cannot import in here because it cause an error like 'ChatPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules: ChatPageModule and SharedPageModule! Please consider moving ChatPage to a higher module that imports ChatPageModule and SharedPageModule.'
    NgxUiLoaderModule,
    
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpProvider,
    HttpAngularProvider,
    HttpNativeProvider,
    GlobalFunctions,
    AuthGuard,
    StatusBar,
    ScreenOrientation,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,useClass: IonicGestureConfig },
    HTTP
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got 1 solution.

Added `entryComponents: [ChatPage]`  to the `@NgModule({})` section in the **shared.module.ts** then imported Shared module in **app.module.ts**